# S.M.A.R.T. Errors of previous hdd or need to replace?

Tags: linux, smart, drive-failure

I ran s.m.a.r.t and came up with some weird errors, although the disk is pretty fresh Power_On_Minutes 427h+41m

I'm curious, are these the errors of previous hdd?

```
Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13729 hours (572 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle
Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 23300 hours (970 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
```

Here is the output

```
# smartctl --all /dev/sda
    smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-51-generic] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..76GSX
    Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK2576GSX
    Serial Number:    Y1J9S0IGS
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 3a5a06b8e
    Firmware Version: GS001A
    User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
    Form Factor:      2.5 inches
    Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
    ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
    SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Thu Dec  1 00:28:22 2016 GMT
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled

    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
    SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

    General SMART Values:
    Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                            was never started.
                                            Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
    Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                            without error or no self-test has ever
                                            been run.
    Total time to complete Offline
    data collection:                (  120) seconds.
    Offline data collection
    capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                            Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                            Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                            command.
                                            Offline surface scan supported.
                                            Self-test supported.
                                            No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                            Selective Self-test supported.
    SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                            power-saving mode.
                                            Supports SMART auto save timer.
    Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                            General Purpose Logging supported.
    Short self-test routine
    recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
    Extended self-test routine
    recommended polling time:        (  81) minutes.
    SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                            SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                            SCT Feature Control supported.
                                            SCT Data Table supported.

    SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
    Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
    ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
      1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
      2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
      3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1229
      4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
      5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
      7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
      8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
      9 Power_On_Minutes        0x0032   036   036   000    Old_age   Always       -       427h+41m
     10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
     12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
    191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
    193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   070   070   000    Old_age   Always       -       304324
    194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27 (Min/Max 20/31)
    196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
    199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
    220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       109
    222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   067   067   000    Old_age   Always       -       13230
    223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       375
    240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

    SMART Error Log Version: 1
    ATA Error Count: 2
            CR = Command Register [HEX]
            FR = Features Register [HEX]
            SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
            SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
            CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
            CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
            DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
            DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
            ER = Error register [HEX]
            ST = Status register [HEX]
    Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
    DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
    SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

    Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 23300 hours (970 days + 20 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      84 51 01 1f 7a 05 e0  Error: ICRC, ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00057a1f = 358943

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      35 00 00 20 76 05 e0 00   6d+01:49:26.915  WRITE DMA EXT
      35 00 00 00 72 05 e0 00   6d+01:49:26.741  WRITE DMA EXT
      35 00 08 80 0f 0c e0 00   6d+01:49:26.741  WRITE DMA EXT
      35 00 08 48 8a c4 e0 00   6d+01:49:26.741  WRITE DMA EXT
      ca 00 08 00 08 14 e9 00   6d+01:49:26.741  WRITE DMA

    Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 13729 hours (572 days + 1 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      84 51 01 3f 8c 4e e0  Error: ICRC, ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x004e8c3f = 5147711

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      35 00 00 40 88 4e e0 00  12d+21:23:20.732  WRITE DMA EXT
      ca 00 08 a8 48 c8 e3 00  12d+21:23:20.731  WRITE DMA
      35 00 08 40 c1 1d e0 00  12d+21:23:20.731  WRITE DMA EXT
      35 00 08 b0 19 14 e0 00  12d+21:23:20.731  WRITE DMA EXT
      35 00 10 28 bf 13 e0 00  12d+21:23:20.731  WRITE DMA EXT

    SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
    No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

    SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
     SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
        1        0        0  Not_testing
        2        0        0  Not_testing
        3        0        0  Not_testing
        4        0        0  Not_testing
        5        0        0  Not_testing
    Selective self-test flags (0x0):
      After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
    If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Does this HDD may fail soon and needs to be replaced?

Comment: It's a $30 drive.  IMO, it's not worth the time and effort trying to investigate it when at the end you may determine you need to replace it.  Just replace it, move on.

Comment: It's a small atom dedicated server so I'm not able to replace it myself. Need some opinion based on the output i posted. The HDD says it has ~400h on while those errors indicate x,xxx hours messages

Comment: The drive failed some time ago. And I don't know why you call it "pretty fresh" as it's clearly well over two years old. The Power_On_Minutes attribute plainly does not reflect the drive's actual service lifetime.

Comment: Read this: https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/

Comment: @Tim, thanks. High Fly Writes consideration look quite interesting.

Comment: If by dedicated server you mean it's rented from a service provider, then my opinion stands.  Only stronger.  You're paying for functional gear.  You shouldn't be paying gear with potential issues (I don't anyway).  Contact your provider and tell them the errors.  They should offer you a replacement or an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, the HDD will be replaced by the service provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you poll for SMART data you're not getting it from some cache, but directly from the drive. It will never show you the results of an old drive. In this case, your drive is failing and it's time to chuck it.

Comment: Thank you, asked for a replacement and it's been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I on the other hand don't see anything even remotely suggesting that the disk is falling. There's no common symptoms of dying disk in counters like:

- **`Reallocated_Event_Count - 0`**
- **`Current_Pending_Sector  - 0`**
- **`Offline_Uncorrectable   - 0`**

But instead you're seeing this:

- **`UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    - 2`**

I would not bother with that. *Cyclic redundancy check* (CRC) is a method of verifying and correcting data after it is sent. What this warning is telling you is that at one point, data being sent/received by the drive failed this check. The most common cause for this is a faulty cable or disk controller. Noise or resistance may cause a bit to be flipped.